# Making layout size 36" x 72" in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, layouts

I need to make a poster to present at a conference and I'm wondering if there's anyway to do this all in ArcGIS 10.1.

Is it possible to change the layout/page size to 36x72 inches?

Comment: One thing to consider when working at this scale is paper size. You need to leave 1-inch margins on the narrow sides in order to fit the whole thing on 36" paper. If you have to print on 42" or 48" paper, it will cost a lot more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible? Sure, just create a new document at any size (doesn't matter), then click File->Page and Print Setup and set the width and height to whatever you want.

As to whether this is practical, I can't say since I don't know what you're trying to do. The complexity of the map depends on the content, not the sheet size, at least until you try to export the whole thing as a jpg at 300dpi, or some equivalent bad idea. Even then, it's just a matter of how long your willing to wait for the export and how much disk space it will consume.